# Minimum out-of-character interactions while still being an RPG?

Tags: game-design

As far as I know, most RPG system requires many out-of-character interactions.

D&D (or other similar combat-oriented RPGs) imply a lot of rolling, tracking numbers, and declaring actions that don't really narratively describe what the PC is doing (e.g. "I use my bonus action for...", "I prepare the spell...", etc.)

Fate (and other narrative-oriented RPGs) also require a lot of out-of-character interactions, such as invoking or creating aspects.

From [the definition for role-playing game on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_game) it would seem that some of those *out-of-character* interactions.:

> *A role-playing game (sometimes spelled roleplaying game and abbreviated to RPG) is a game in which players assume the roles of
>   characters in a fictional setting. Players take responsibility for
>   acting out these roles within a narrative, either through literal
>   acting or through a process of structured decision-making of character
>   development. **Actions taken within many games succeed or fail
>   according to a formal system of rules and guidelines.***

That would be because *at first* it'd seem like that formal system of rules require doing some action that characters don't directly do.

My question is:

**How could a game be an RPG (as described by the Wikipedia) while keeping *out-of-character* interactions from players at the minimum?**

I'd like to center the question around the mechanics needed for fullfiling the definition that would require the least *out-of-character* interactions.

For this question, I'm defining *in-character*  as when players describe what actions the character is doing in a narrative way (as would be done in a book).

Also, note that the question centers around players being *out-of-character*. It wouldn't matter much for this question whether the GM acts *in-character* or *out-of-character*.

Comment: I've attempted to copyedit the question a bit and make the question clearer... I'm not sure if it's still a "shopping" question, but it does seem more answerable to me.

Comment: That said, the last part about the definition of an RPG seems less relevant now that the question has been edited to be about the mechanics that maximize it rather than looking for such a system itself. Individual system mechanics won't necessarily meet that definition, since they're just pieces of a game, rather than the game itself. You could still include a reminder that you're intending to play this as an RPG, though.

Comment: Even without the bonus question, it could still be seen as a very (too?) broad "name me all the mechanics that can/could maximise IC time"...

Comment: Is the question *How can a game's rules be designed so that players spend only minimal time out of character referring to the game's rules?*  or is the question *What game rules from published RPGs make it so that players spend only minimal time out of character referring to the game's rules?* or is the question something else that I can't see? (Keep in mind that neither of those rephrased questions, though, is site-appropriate. However, *How can I make it so players in my [system] campaign spend only minimal time out of character referring to the game's rules?* totally is site-appropriate.)

Comment: Related question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60596/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-player-driven-versus-gm-driven-mech