# Does re-stealthing gain a bonus on roll if the NPC is engaged in other combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stealth, sneak-attack

In Pathfinder.
As a rogue, if I make a successful ranged sneak attack and attempt to re-stealth (purpose I want to make another sneak attack)
If that enemy is engaged in combat (let's say with other PCs... the NPC would obviously be distracted and stealthing should be easier.

Is there a rule to back this up or shoot this down?
I've seen this takes a -20 on re-stealthing.
But if my dwarf is raising a great axe at the NPC, certainly he iant concerned with where the sneak attack came from.

Thoughts?

Somewhat related to this question:
[How often to roll Stealth vs. Perception?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/how-often-to-roll-stealth-vs-perception)

Answer (score 2):

### Your question really needs to go to your GM.

The question of whether the enemy would pay attention to you or the Dwarf is up to your GM, and they may allow it if you can make valid points. They may also stick to RAW.

It may be an uphill battle, though... it may be hard to justify that a Greataxe is any more scary than a arrow/bolt/dart hitting you them the neck.

### RAW, everyone in combat is aware of everyone they can perceive at all times, unless you make an effort to hide yourself.

There are specific rules for ranged attacks and maintaining Stealth:

> Your Stealth immediately ends after you make an attack roll, whether or not the attack is successful (except when sniping as noted below).
>
> ...
>
> Sniping
>
> If you’ve already successfully used Stealth at least 10 feet from your target, you can make one ranged attack and then immediately use Stealth again. You take a –20 penalty on your Stealth check to maintain your obscured location.

As long as you can roll Stealth 20 higher than your opponent's Perception and retain some form of Concealment, they will not be able to detect you. Everyone, and especially Rogues, have methods of reducing this penalty.

- Stealth Unchained is an optional but commonly used rule, accessible through the Unchained Rogue ability [Rogue's Edge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/Rogue-unchained/#TOC-Rogue-s-Edge-Ex-) or the [Signature Skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/signature-skill-general) Feat, that reduces the penalty to 10 when you have at least 5 ranks in Stealth.
- The [Expert Sniper](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/expert-sniper-combat/) feat (also available to Rogues as a [Talent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/superior-sniper)) also reduces the penalty by 10.
- The Rogue Advanced Talent [Stealthy Sniper](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-advanced-talents/stealthy-sniper-ex) *also* reduces the penalty by 10.
- The [Sniping](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/sniping-rtt) line of magical weapon properties give you a Competence bonus to Stealth specifically when Sniping (but you're better off getting something constant like [Shadow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/shadow/))
- Honorable mention, the Advanced Talent [Hide in Plain Sight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-advanced-talents/hide-in-plain-sight-ex) (as well as the Shadowdancer ability it emulates) provides the necessary Concealment to roll Stealth in many places that you may not otherwise be able to.

*Note: The first 3 abilities *reduce the penalty* to Stealth, meaning that taking 2 or all 3 results in the same 0 Penalty. The third would not provide a bonus to the check.