# Can an attack be made without triggering combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, attack

This is a follow up question to:
[Does NPC engaging in combat remove penalty for re-stealthing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144664/does-npc-engaging-in-combat-remove-penalty-for-re-stealthing)

Is there a scenario when a surprise attack can be made without triggering combat? Maybe there is a different term for it than "surprise attack".

For example, If the entire party is hidden, can a surprise attack be made without triggering combat?

Scenario :
Party is hidden behind a castle wall, Rogue fires a crossbow bolt thru an embrasure / arrowslit. The NPC down below would only know a general direction. But it seems there is no way for that NPC to engage in combat.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. The referenced question asks "what should happen if...? "  I am asking the opposite: "how to avoid triggering combat" A completely separate question.

Comment: To clarify, the other question is how to start combat. This is how to NOT start combat with an attack. Is that even possible?

Comment: I believe what you're asking is akin to playing a video game and trying to snipe an enemy without triggering their AI. The question reads like "I want to be able to attack, but don't let the bad guys react." Just because they can't immediately/efficiently attack, doesn't mean you're not in combat. They can call for help, search, seek cover and any number of actions. So the question of "how not to enter combat" is moot. You've entered combat. Therefore, refer to the other question of how to handle combat when stealthy.

Comment: @MivaScott That sounds like the start of a great answer. You should post it as one, and not as a comment.

Comment: @GreySage, would that I could. But the question is closed so there is no way to add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there could be consequences to the battle, then yes, combat should be triggered.

That's really up to the DM's discretion. If it were a situation where a battle would only serve to waste time and would most certainly go in favor of the players, then yes I would most likely skip the combat. However, if the guard were to begin yelling, which brought more guards and alerted enemies, then the encounter has consequences.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.